# Determine the arithmetic functions satisfying these relations

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I'm finding various arithmetic functions satisfying this relation such that $f * f = f.$

Note that $*$ means a dirichlet multiplication (convolution). So, by definition of the dirichlet multiplication, we can see that $f * f = f$ would be $\sum_{d|n} f(d)f(n/d) = f(n)$ for some integer $n$. Specifically, we can see that $f(1) = 0$ or $1$ and $f(p) = 0$ or any number if $f(1) = 1$ for a prime $p$.

But, for the general number $n$, I could not find the arithmetic function satisfying this relation.

Comment: Assume that $f(p)$ is some non-zero constant. What can you say about $f(p^n)$ for a  natural number $n$?

Comment: Wait, how could you decide the value of $f$($p^n$)? I mean, if n = $p^n$, then $f*f$($p^n$) = $f$(1)$f$($p^n$) + $f$($p$)$f$($p^{n-1}$) + ... + $f$($p^n$)$f$(1) = $f$($p^n$). If $f$(p) is not equal to zero, there are many values for $f$(p^m) such than m less than n, to satisfy the above equation.

Comment: Rewrite the condition as $f \ast (1 - f) = 0$ and prove that if $f \ast g = 0$ then either $f = 0$ or $g = 0$. This is essentially the claim that the ring of formal Dirichlet series is an integral domain.

Comment: with $g(k) = f(p^k)$ you get $g \ast g(k) = g(k)$ (where $\ast$ is the normal convolution this time) and the two solution are $g(k) = 0$ and $g(k) = \delta(k)$, i.e. $f(n) = 0$ or $\delta(n-1)$  ( @QiaochuYuan this is essentially the claim that the ring of formal Power series is an integral domain)

Comment: @user1952009 You got it.

Comment: @user1952009 I'm still confused. Why did you define $g$($k$) = $f$($p^k$)? And, what is the delta?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Is it possible to use the distributive law in the operation of convolution? So, did you mean that $f  * 1 - f * f = 0$ is equal to the original relation $ f * f = f$?

Comment: @user366855 $\delta(n) = 1_{n= 0}$ is the neutral element of the usual convolution. the neutral element of the Dirichlet convolution being $\delta(n-1)$. (and $1$ in general denotes the constant sequence $1$)

Comment: @user1952009 I'm sorry that I can't understand your point. Could you elaborate on that further?

Comment: $f(n) = f \ast f (n)  \implies f(p^k) = f \ast f(p^k) \implies g(k)= g \ast g(k)$ (the last $\ast$ being normal convolution, and $g(k) = f(p^k)$. see also what happens when multiplying two Euler products) overall the ring of formal Dirichlet series is an integral domain iff the ring of power formal series is an integral domain